# Linux compilation error: "Missing file arch/x86/boot/bzImage"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I’m trying to compile Linux, but I keep getting the following error:

```
sudo make install

sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.14.28-2018840814 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
System.map "boot/"

*** Missing file: arch/x86/boot/bzImage
*** you need to run "make before "make install".
```

I followed this direction, but I got stuck on *make install*:

```
make mrproper
make menuconfig
make -j4
sudo make modules_install
sudo cp .config /boot/config-`make kernelrelease`
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Did you cross compile?

Comment: Any errors while running `make` ? Pretty sure kernel compilation fails and bzImage is not generated

Answer (score 3):

I have Linux 5.19.9 kernel from source in a ubuntu 20.04.5.

my issue when I run

$make -j4

$sudo make modules_install -j4

$sudo make install -j4

INSTALL/boot

*** Missing file: arch/x86/boot/bzImage

*** you need to run "make before "make install".

solution:
$make bzImage

[another error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKOzu.jpg)

reason was zstd not available

then i run
$sudo apt-get install zstd

$make -j4

$sudo make modules_install -j4

$sudo make install -j4

$sudo update-grub

$sudo reboot

check if kernel compile or not my running command

$uname -r

it work fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was compiling the Linux 5.3.11 kernel from source in a Mint 19.2 system and ran into the same issue.

The creation of bzImage is missing in your script. 
Before modules_install you should type:

```
# make bzImage
```

In my case the files are located in:

```
./arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage
./arch/x86/boot/bzImage
```

Then, the rest of the steps.

Comment: Solved the issue!

Comment: For Arm64 use `make Image`